# How to remove border around such as image below(and with responsive)

Tags: html, css

How to remove border like this with html/css
 [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BlC9.jpg)

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Be more specific please.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this image tag to your html.

```
<img src="yourImage.jpg">
```

and style it with following CSS rule.

```
img { border: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but, This includes multiple logo images

Comment: For this purpose you should create many logo files. You can use a programm like Gimp for that. After that you can style all logos as you want to with HTML and CSS. This is much easier than every JavaScript solution to remove/hide this broders in your file.